# How indexing will affect the stored procedure performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working with SQL Server 2008.

I have two tables like this:

`Location_tbl` structure is like this:

```
 Locid    int 
 LocName  varchar(150)
```

`Locid` is the primary key

`TrTransaction_tbl` structure is like this:

```
transactID    int
TBarcode      varchar(20)
Locid         int
PlateNo       varchar(20)
dtime         datetime
DelEcode      nvarchar(50)
Paydate       datetime
KeyRoomDate   datetime
DelDate       datetime
Status        int
```

In this table `transactID` is the primary key and `locid` is a foreign key.

In the transaction table I have more than 200 000 rows, daily increasing around 30 000 records.. I haven't implemented any indexing on my transaction table.. so my stored procedure execution takes a long time.

I added an index to my `TrTransaction_tbl.locid` like this:

```
create index transactlocid on transaction_tbl (Locid asc)
```

I want to know if this index will help my stored procedure run faster?

This will affect anything in the table or records?

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_fetchreqVehicleinPodiumtestnew1]
   @locid INTEGER = NULL
AS BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @TodayMinus7Days DATETIME
   Declare @krrt integer
   Declare @DT integer
   SET @TodayMinus7Days = getdate()-1

   SELECT  
       t.TBarcode, t.PlateNo, t.DelEcode,
       datediff(MINUTE, t.PayDate,
             CASE t.Status
                WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
                WHEN 4 THEN t.KeyRoomDate
                When 5 THEN  t.KeyRoomDate
                End) as KRRT,

             datediff(MINUTE,t.PayDate,
             CASE t.Status
              WHEN 3 THEN GETDATE()
              WHEN 4 THEN GETDATE()
             WHEN 5 THEN t.DelDate
             END) as DT

   FROM    
       dbo.Transaction_tbl t
   WHERE   
       ([status] IN (3,4) AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3
         AND locid = @locid AND dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days)
   ORDER BY  
       paydate
       end
```

if i create index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TRANSACTION ON transaction_tbl
(
    Locid ASC, DTime ASC, Status ASC, DelDate ASC
)
```

this **dtime** means ,,,am taking the current time of saving each records,,if i give index to this,,my insertion will slow right??

Comment: I doubt that that index will help much.  To be sure, we would need to see the query plan and what other indexes are already on the table.

Comment: sir i want to confirm if i give indexing like that that will increase the performance right

Comment: i don't have any more index in that table.i only created index for locid..

Comment: sir i given this line:DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3 ,,i want to exit status 5 records up to 3 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt very much that that index will help.  It is really impossible to tell without a query plan, but you might try an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TRANSACTION ON transaction_tbl
(
    Locid ASC, DTime ASC, Status ASC, DelDate ASC
)
```

---

This index will allow the `WHERE` clause conditions to be resolved entirely from the index.  Ideally it will search for LocId, and DTime, and then predicate-resolve Status and DelDate.  Then it will still have to go back and lookup the rest of the columns from the main table (so depending on the number of matches it expects, it could still skip this index, but I'd need the query plan to tell that).

---

As HLGEM points out in the comments, `DelDate` is *already* a `DATETIME`, so there's no need to convert it.  So the following where clause should work better:

```
WHERE   locid = @locid
  AND   dtime >= @TodayMinus7Days
  AND   (( [status] IN (3,4) )
      OR 
         ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, DelDate, GETDATE()) <= 3)
        )
```

Comment: sir why we are creating index for four variable?

Comment: @user3262364 Because those are the four columns in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: ok..thanks for replay..if i created index like this it will affect anything in the existing records?? no right?

Comment: @user3262364 - Indexes don't change data, they're an extra data-structure that resides along side the table.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Indexing the `DelDate` field will likely be inconsequential due to `DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3` needing to be restructured, and due to `DTime` already being a range seek.

Comment: sir i given this line:DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3 ,,i want to exit status 5 records up to 3 minute

Comment: @RBarryYoung sir so if i have to give indexing to DelDate  that will make any problem?

Comment: @HLGEM that i can write without recast?

Comment: instead of that if i write like this:DATEDIFF(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE() <= 3..that will get same effect?

Comment: @MatBailie No it's not inconsequential, granted it won't be used as an index, but it will have the same effect as if it was in an `INCLUDE` clause (whose syntax I could not remember off the top of my head).  That was my intent.

Comment: @HLGEM still need the `datepart` argument don't you?  Right now its (n), so it's in minutes (which seems odd).

Comment: @HLGEM - Surely `DelDate >= DATEADD(minute, -3, GETDATE())` has numerous potential performance advantages?

Comment: @RBarryYoung sir,,this DTime means ,,,am taking the current time of saving each records,,if i give index to this,,my insertion will slow right?

Comment: @user3262364 Yes, adding indexes does slow SQL operations that modify data: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.  However, the performance cost of adding a single index is small (on the order of 10%), but the performance *benefit* can be huge (on the order of 10x to 1000x).  Therefore, as long as the index works and does improve your performance, its cost is well worth it.  On the other hand, indexes that do not work or are not used should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have added an index on `locid` and both your `WHERE` clause branches have a specific filter on locid, the optimizer *should* be able to significantly improve the performance of this query.

If it doesn't, I would suggest "factoring out" the `locid = @locid` clause out of the `OR` construct; that might help the optimizer if it is getting confused.

Certainly it would be a good idea to turn on the "show actual execution plan" option in SSMS and see whether it is generating a good plan or not.  If you post the screenshot of the plan, we can probably see whether you are getting the improvement you want or if there is something else that could be done.